# What does a "Buffer cache hit ratio" of 9990 mean?

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2012

I got this query from a [blog post](http://www.sqlshack.com/sql-server-memory-performance-metrics-part-4-buffer-cache-hit-ratio-page-life-expectancy/):

```
SELECT object_name, counter_name, cntr_value
FROM sys.dm_os_performance_counters
WHERE [object_name] LIKE '%Buffer Manager%'
AND [counter_name] = 'Buffer cache hit ratio'
```

The post said that it would give me a percentage of hits to the cache.  It seemed to indicate that it would be a value of 0-100 (it showed a result of 87).

But when I run it I am getting very high numbers.  Here is an example:

```
object_name               counter_name             cntr_value  
SQLServer:Buffer Manager  Buffer cache hit ratio   9990
```

Does this mean 99.90 %?

If not, what does it mean?  And how can I get the real value?

NOTE: I have gotten values as low as **257** and as high as **352363**

Incase it is relevant, here are a few other server stats:

- Page life expectancy: 145
- Page reads/sec: 1,380,009,009

Comment: Sorry, but the blog post is wrong. :-( [Denis Gobo gets it right](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/datamgmt/dbprogramming/use-sys-dm_os_performance_counters-to-ge/)...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Confusing, right?

Well, to *actually* get the ratio, you'll need to do it yourself using the `Buffer cache hit ratio base` in addition to the `Buffer cache hit ratio` by taking the result from `Buffer cache hit ratio / Buffer cache hit ratio base`.

Try the below query (from [Less Than Dot](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DBAdmin/MSSQLServerAdmin/use-sys-dm_os_performance_counters-to-ge/)), which should give you the % you're looking for:

```
SELECT (a.cntr_value * 1.0 / b.cntr_value) * 100.0 as BufferCacheHitRatio
FROM sys.dm_os_performance_counters  a
JOIN  (SELECT cntr_value, OBJECT_NAME 
    FROM sys.dm_os_performance_counters  
    WHERE counter_name = 'Buffer cache hit ratio base'
        AND OBJECT_NAME = 'SQLServer:Buffer Manager') b ON  a.OBJECT_NAME = b.OBJECT_NAME
WHERE a.counter_name = 'Buffer cache hit ratio'
AND a.OBJECT_NAME = 'SQLServer:Buffer Manager'
```

Comment: You should credit [Denis Gobo](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/datamgmt/dbprogramming/use-sys-dm_os_performance_counters-to-ge/)...

Comment: @Aaron One of those days - attribution added

Comment: I am confuse by the results I get, see related [How can you have a Buffer cache hit ratio of 100% with PLE of 103?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/235185/21924)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have a default instance of SQL server, but named instance, you have to modify query like this:

```
  SELECT (a.cntr_value * 1.0 / b.cntr_value) * 100.0 as BufferCacheHitRatio
FROM sys.dm_os_performance_counters  a
JOIN  (SELECT cntr_value, OBJECT_NAME 
    FROM sys.dm_os_performance_counters  
    WHERE counter_name = 'Buffer cache hit ratio base'
        AND OBJECT_NAME LIKE '%:Buffer Manager%') b ON  a.OBJECT_NAME = b.OBJECT_NAME
WHERE a.counter_name = 'Buffer cache hit ratio'
AND a.OBJECT_NAME LIKE '%:Buffer Manager%'
```