# How can you have a Buffer cache hit ratio of 100% with PLE of 103?

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2017, plan-cache

I found [What does a "Buffer cache hit ratio" of 9990 mean?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/88784/21924) (*I was getting result of 9000+ from a blog that was wrong*) and used the [solution by LowlyDBA/Denis Gobo](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/88788/21924) combined with the PLE checker from [Denis Gobo](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/datamgmt/dbprogramming/use-sys-dm_os_performance_counters-to-ge/) and got a Buffer cache hit ratio of 100% with PLE of 103, how is that possible?

The buffer chache hit ratio of 100% is saying the 100% of pages needed are being found in memory, but the PLE is saying pages are only staying in memory for a couple of minutes.

Maybe there is some PLE value, below which buffer chache hit ratio does not add value?

```
SELECT (a.cntr_value * 1.0 / b.cntr_value) * 100.0 as BufferCacheHitRatio
FROM sys.dm_os_performance_counters  a
JOIN  (SELECT cntr_value, OBJECT_NAME 
    FROM sys.dm_os_performance_counters  
    WHERE counter_name = 'Buffer cache hit ratio base'
        AND OBJECT_NAME = 'SQLServer:Buffer Manager') b ON  a.OBJECT_NAME = b.OBJECT_NAME
WHERE a.counter_name = 'Buffer cache hit ratio'
AND a.OBJECT_NAME = 'SQLServer:Buffer Manager'

SELECT *
FROM sys.dm_os_performance_counters  
WHERE counter_name = 'Page life expectancy'
AND OBJECT_NAME = 'SQLServer:Buffer Manager'
```

[image: PLE 103]

### Why I care:

My instance is SQL 2017 CU13, heavy OLTP, with 4GB of RAM for the SQL instance (*single instance, 6GB RAM on the server*).

I know that more than 1.5GB of RAM is devoted to the Plan Cache, according to [some sources](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/222091/21924) of the 4GB of RAM here, the Plan Cache should be able to use 3GB (*found similar details several places, but all are old and none are Microsoft*)

```
Select ( SUM(size_in_bytes)) /1024 /1024 AS size_in_MB FROM sys.dm_exec_cached_plans
```

I have not used any [xevents yet to measure plan eviction,](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/222092/21924) just trying to understand things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Buffer cache hit ratio` and `Buffer cache hit ratio base` are measurements for a very small timeslice. You just ran your query at times when the recent reads hit the buffer cache.

For proof, just look at the raw values over time - they go up and down.

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.dm_os_performance_counters
WHERE counter_name IN ('Buffer cache hit ratio','Buffer cache hit ratio base')
```

I would recommend a look at other metrics (perhaps `sys.dm_io_virtual_file_stats`?) to see what kind of IO you're driving.